# Appcelerator - Programmatic Toggle of Switch in Custom TableViewRow

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a custom TableViewRow with a title and switch like below:

rowFilter.xml

```
<TableViewRow id="rowFilter">
    <View id="vwItemHeader">
        <Label id="lblItemHeader"></Label>
    </View>
    <View id="vwFilterStatus">
        <Switch id="swtFilterStatus" onChange="swtFilterStatusChange"></Switch>
    </View>
</TableViewRow>
```

rowFilter.js

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};

var swtFilterStatusChange_callback;

initialize();

function initialize() {
    // Initialize filter row UI
    $.lblItemHeader.text = args.title;
    $.swtFilterStatus.value = args.value;

    // Callback
    swtFilterStatusChange_callback = args.callback;
};
```

In a view I call Browse, I programmatically add these custom rows as follows:

```
var args = { title: item.title, value: item.value, callback: swtFilterStatusChanged, };

var newRow = Alloy.createController('rowFilter', args).getView('rowFilter');
```

This works just as intended.  However now I want to add a check/uncheck all row.  How do I programmatically toggle a switch within my custom rows?

I've tried creating the following function in rowFilter.js (and a similar one for toggle off):

```
exports.toggleOn = function() {
    if ($.swtFilterStatus.value == false) {
        $.swtFilterStatus.value = true;
        swtFilterStatusChange();
    }
};
```

And I've also tried this:

```
$.toggleOn = function() {
}
```

::EDIT:: Here is how I handle the check/uncheck all switch.

```
function allSwitch_Change(value) {
    $.tblFilters.data[0].rows.forEach(function(row) {
        if (value) {
            row.toggleOn();
        }
        else {
            row.toggleOf();
        }
    }
}
```

Then changing the Browse.js row above that does Alloy.createController with the following:

```
var newRow = require('rowFilter');
newRow.initialize(args);
```

But I just get an exception on the line with the require statement saying "Couldn't find module:rowFilter for architecture: x86_64".

What am I doing wrong and how do I implement a check/uncheck all row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

rowFilter.js

```
var args = arguments[0] || {};

var swtFilterStatusChange;

initialize();

function initialize() {
    // Initialize filter row UI
    $.lblItemHeader.text = args.title;
    $.swtFilterStatus.value = args.value;

    // Callback
    swtFilterStatusChange = args.callback;
};

$.on('toggleOn',function(){
    if ($.swtFilterStatus.value == false) {
        $.swtFilterStatus.value = true;
        swtFilterStatusChange();
    }
});
```

browser.js

```
var args = { title: item.title, value: item.value, callback: swtFilterStatusChanged, };

var newRow = Alloy.createController('rowFilter', args);

newRow.trigger('toggleOn');
```

Other options to achieve your goal:

1. Global Events - `Ti.App.addEventListener` and `Ti.App.fireEvent`. Easy to implement, but has potential memory leak. Make sure to call `Ti.App.removeEventListener` after table row removed.
2. Get the switch view from the table row's `children`. Manually fire the event on it.
3. Store the reference to the callback `swtFilterStatusChanged` somewhere and call it later.

Comment: Now I get exception with this message: "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'row.trigger(\"toggleOff\")')".  See my edit showing how I call this in another function.

Comment: Not sure if it matters but I attempt to toggle the row switches in a separate function from where I create the controllers.

Comment: My bad. Didn't see you called `getView` on the controller. `trigger` is a function of the controller itself. So you have to store the reference of the controller somewhere for access later. Answer updated.

Comment: My toggle functions are called when I store an array of the row controllers in Browse.  However, when I programmatically toggle the switch, the UI does not refresh.  Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Figured it out.  Thanks for your help!